# CD quality bitrate

Tags: audio

**Question 1**: Here are two facts that I know about CD quality audio:

1. Audio is sampled to 16 bits at a rate of 44.1 kHz
2. The bitrate is 1411 kbps.

I can't quite work out the math.

$
\frac{16\ \text{bits}}{} \times \frac{44.1 k}{sec} = \frac{705.6\ \text{kbits}}{sec}
$

which does not equal 1411 kbps. Why?

**Question 2**: I remember my EE professor telling me that 44.1 kHz is the highest frequency that humans can hear. Why, then, do some online music services offer "high resolution" streams or files that are recorded at 96 kHz or even 192 kHz? Can only people with mutant-level hearing take advantage of those sampling rates?

Comment: Are you *sure* you're seeing "96 kHz" and "192 kHz"?  Far more likely is 96 kbps and 192 kpbs (kilobits per second) since these are common AAC/MP3 encoding bitrates.

Comment: @EricTowers: Look at this offer page from the Qobuz music streaming service. It clearly says: `FLAC 24-Bit up to 192 kHz`. https://www.qobuz.com/us-en/music/streaming/offers . Also Amazon Music HD: `Up to 24-bit / 192 kHz` https://www.amazon.com/music/unlimited/why-hd

Comment: These are both marketing copy.  I'm fairly jaded about the technical accuracy of marketing copy.  For instance, I clearly recall ads for computers having 0.064 bits of memory.  ("64 mb".)  *Maybe* this is an analog sampling rate, but I would bet a quarter it's the codec bitrate.

Comment: @EricTowers: Here's a Sony DAC that `Supports PCM 32bit/768 kHz` https://electronics.sony.com/audio/audio-components-turntables/amplifiers/p/tazh1es

Comment: @EricTowers we are pretty sure we are talking about 96 kHz and 192 kHz PCM streams, at up to 24 or 32 bits per sample. No codecs involved.

Answer (score 11):

What is missing from your calculations is that it requires a multiplier of two because CD quality audio is two channels for stereo. 2 * 44.1 kHz * 16 = 1411.2 kbps

The answer to your second question is twofold.

First of all, human hearing range is typically said to go up to 20 kHz, not to 44.1 kHz. However to sample data up to 20kHz, it needs to be sampled at above 40 kHz, and to have some margin for various reasons (analog reconstruction filters among others), CDs use 44.1 kHz sampling rate.

Second, indeed, there is no technical reason to transfer mastered audio recordings to consumers at higher rates than 16-bit 44.1 or 16-bit 48 kHz, as humans do not have the auditory sensors to receive frequencies past 20 kHz. The reason these high-resolution streams exist is purely marketing and demand.

However, in the studio it can make sense to record and store intermediate tracks at higher resolution before the final downmix. And even when playing back 48 kHz streams, typically modern DACs first digitally upsample the sampling rate to allow for better audio quality with cheaper analog filters.

Comment: audio sigma-delta upsample by a factor of 64x or maybe 128x and allegedly require just a passive 1st-order RC filter.  i have seen audio gear use a 3rd-order Butterworth LPF.  Just to avoid op-amps, i might suggest using a cascaded passive RC filter.  still no op-amp to saturate or distort.

Comment: "*to sample data up to 20kHz, it needs to be sampled at least at 40 kHz*" -- This should be "needs to be sampled at more than 40 kHz (i.e. fs>40k, not fs>=40k)", otherwise it's implied that 40 kHz is enough, but that will get you a net zero if the samples fall on the crossing points.

Comment: @concernedcitizen Thanks, I updated. I could have also written "up to but not including 20kHz" but it does not matter much which around it is. For the human ear it makes little difference if it is <= 20kHz or just < 20 kHz, but it is important to convey the theory right.

Comment: I've always assumed that the 20 kHz figure for the upper frequency limit of human perception follows some kind of normal distribution so that the number of people who can hear sounds beyond that threshold decreases quickly. If that's true, there may still be quite a few who'd benefit from 48 kHz or even higher sampling rates. Is there a physiological limitation that that sets a hard cut-off point to the upper limit of human frequency perception?

Comment: @Schmuddi I believe that's already taken into account in the 20kHz number, so the typical maximum is more like 17kHz

Comment: @Schmuddi the 20 kHz number is simply good enough for a commonly stated value. Babies can hear above that and adults less, so there is considerable variation among individuals. Compared to 44.1 kHz, 48 kHz is not used to get higher frequencies up to 24 kHz, it is to have a larger transition bandwidth from passing 20 kHz to filtering 24kHz which allows for less costly filters.

Comment: When I read "audiophile" forums, folks there state they can hear the difference between CD quality and "high resolution" 96 kHz. They say something like "the sound is fuller because there're more information." But how is that possible if humans can only hear up to a sampling rate of 40 kHz?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 it most likely isn't, and they're just tricking themselves. Audiophiles are generally not the most scientifically rigorous group of people. I wouldn't trust anything they say unless it's backed by some kind of blind trial

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Unless the tests are performed in controlled test environment for comparing two recordings, the subjects may show bias because better specs make them feel warm and fuzzy inside. Maybe soon we have videophiles who would like to have TVs with color spectrum extended to the ultraviolet and infrared range too, even if we don't have the sensors in out eyes to detect that.

Comment: @Schmuddi, the upper frequency limit is taken as the point where the threshold of perception crosses the threshold of pain.  You can hear sounds above that point, but only if they're painfully loud.

Comment: Why does this professional/audiophile DAC say `All digital inputs on the DAC3 support native 192 kHz PCM or DSD64 conversion`  if humans can't hear above a sampling rate of 2x20 kHz? https://benchmarkmedia.com/collections/digital-to-analog-audio-converter/products/benchmark-dac3-hgc-digital-to-analog-audio-converter

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Why do people buy gold-plated HDMI cables?  It's a digital transfer, you get the exact data or you don't.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: The audiophile argument about "high quality" cables is that such cables reduce jitter. In Internet networking, that's an important issue, but I'm not familiar with short interconnects.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Why any device goes to 192 kHz? If it is a professional audio device used by professionals. Professionals already have the intermediate tracks recorded in DSD or 192 kHz and a device at high price tag is expected to play any format and rate you can think of. Cheap computer motherboards can play at 192 kHz too.

Comment: The way I see it is - if for example you want to get samples of a 20 kHz sinusoidal waveform, then sampling that waveform with a 40 kHz sampling frequency would give you just 1 point (or maybe 2 points) for each period of the 20 kHz waveform, which is probably the equivalent of very 'chunky' graphics.

Comment: @Kenny It definitely gives you exactly two points per period, not one or maybe 2. And it is not equivalent of very 'chunky' graphics at all.

Comment: @Justme - if both sample points happen to be hypothetically at the zero crossings of the sinusoid, then that's a bit of a problem for interpolation. It's chunky graphics, because resolution with just two points isn't great. Actually not good at all.

Comment: @Kenny With exactly two samples per period, you also hit the limit of Nyquist. Samplig rate can't be exactly 40 kHz when sampling exactly 20 kHz sine wave. Sampling rate must be more than double the sine frequency you want to record. So it violated the rule of sampling the signal properly anyway.